# How to set ARMV6 assembler codegen to ARM mode in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, build-settings

In Xcode 4.3.2, I get this build recommendation:

*Upgrade ARMV6 assembler codegen from THUMB to ARM mode.*

I can either accept or reject the recommendation and the change gets made for me. The problem is that this recommendation seems to pop up only after I've built and run it a few times. I would like to integrate this setting into my defaults, but I can't find the setting in Build Settings that would let me do this preemptively.

Answer (score 0):

The setting you want is "GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT". I determined this by examining (through version control) the change made to the project settings after I let Xcode make this change for me, and that was the setting I saw.

I've seen this in the project/target settings in two ways:
GCC_THUMB_SUPPORT
and
Compile for Thumb

but I am pretty convinced they are the same setting.